# Is there way how to use paddingEnd and paddingStart with minSdkVersion <17?

Tags: android, android-layout

I just have found there is `android:marginStart`, `android:marginEnd`, `android:paddingStart` and `android:paddingEnd` in API 17. This margins and paddings use text orientation. Is there way to use this definitions and build application for Android 2.2+ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is way to use new support for Right To Left languages on devices with Android 4.2+ and support lower Android versions at same time. There is [a blog article on Android Developers](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) about it.