# Adding padding start to a LinearLayout

Tags: android

Is it possible to add `paddingStart` to a view? right now I know to add padding `view.addPadding(left,Top,Right,Bottom);`

Comment: `paddingStart`, `paddlingLeft` are same.  If you're adding left padding means you're adding start padding

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917118/is-there-way-how-to-use-paddingend-and-paddingstart-with-minsdkversion-17

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there way how to use paddingEnd and paddingStart with minSdkVersion <17?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917118/is-there-way-how-to-use-paddingend-and-paddingstart-with-minsdkversion-17)

Comment: @SrikarReddy i dont think so because in RTL it matters however LTR doesnt take any account for it. I am working on  a multilingual application with RTL Layouts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
view.setPaddingRelative(start,top,end,bottom);
```